# Gravitational Potential outside thin shell

Tags: newtonian-gravity, potential

Here's the first part of the proof in Feynman's lectures:

\begin{equation*}
dm=2\pi y\mu\,ds=\frac{2\pi y\mu\,dx}{\sin\theta}=
\frac{2\pi y\mu\,dx\,a}{y}=2\pi a\mu\,dx,
\end{equation*}

I don't get how he replaced ds by dx/sin

Here's the link to the lecture: http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_13.html

Comment: Because $dx$ and $ds$ form a triangle whose sine of the specified angle $\theta$ is $dx/ds$

Comment: I could guess that. I want to know how the triangle looks like. If dx and ds are two sides, what is the third side?

Comment: You could call the other side $dy=\sqrt{ds^2-dx^2}$.

Comment: Aaargh.how is the angle theta in the triangle? Can you please draw and show? How did the triangle come about exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the picture in the link, you can construct a triangle as such:

[image: Triangle Constuction]

As you can see from the gray triangle, $\sin \theta= \frac{dx}{ds}$, or, as questioned:
$$ds=\frac{dx}{\sin \theta}$$